# Custom Firebase RSS Feed

Tags: firebase

I have setup a Firebase database to pull in feeds from Feedthefire.in and it works great; it lists the feeds from my clients page in an unordered list with a link back to the original article on their website.

My code looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ref = new Firebase("https://aonews.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.child("meta").once("value", function(snapshot) {
        $("#e-title").html(snapshot.val().description);
    });
    ref.child("articles").limit(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        var pubDate = snapshot.val();
        var article = snapshot.val();
        var link = $("<a>", {
            "href": article.link,
            "target": "_blank"
        });
        $("#e-list").append($("<li>").append(link.html(article.title)));
    });
```

What I would like to do is display the title, a short snippet of the feed description and then a link to the original article.  I am just learning this and learn best by seeing examples, but I am unsure of what I should search for to find my answers.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's unclear what the question is here. Your code seems to download and display feeds already.

Comment: Thanks Kato. Yes, the code itself does pull info in from Firebase with the above code, but pulls it in as an unordered list of just the links to the original article.  I noticed in the Firebase database, that there is description meta which includes the entire post content.  What I am trying to do is display a non linkable title, with a snippet of the description meta and then a link to the original article.  I assume there is a way of pulling it into my site and displaying it since it exists in my Firebase database, but being a noob, I am having trouble sorting it out.  Thank you again.

Comment: The `article` object you've abstracted from the snapshot should have pretty much any data you want to access. Try logging that object to the console and examining its contents.